# How to fetch table header from oracle database into excel

Tags: excel, oracle, powershell, oracle11g, sqlplus

I am trying to fetch data from an oracle database table to an excel sheet.
Below is the code written in powershell.

The sequence of activity is connect to the database, spool data into a variable and push the same into the excel.
The problem is I am unable to fetch the **column header** from the db table. I have tried various combinations of set statements but none seem to work for me.
The db is Oracle 11g Express Edition.

```
$sqlQuery=@"
set heading on
set colsep '|'
set pagesize 0
set feedback off
select * From countries
where rownum<4;
"@

$output=$sqlQuery |sqlplus -silent hr/hr@localhost:1521/xe

$rows =$output.Length 

$cols = $output[0].Split('|').Length

$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$excel.Visible =$true

$excel.Workbooks.Add()

$workbook=$excel.ActiveWorkbook

$worksheet=$workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

for($i=0;$i -lt $rows;$i++) {
    $rowdata = $output[$i].split('|')
    for($j=0;$j -lt $cols;$j++) {
        $worksheet.Cells.Item($i+1,$j+1)=$rowdata[$j]
    }

}
```

[image]

With the `set pagesize 0` removed, below is the output I get in the excel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove `SET PAGESIZE 0`, it causes no heading effect.

This is OK:

```
SQL> select * From dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME                LOC
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH             DALLAS
        30 SALES                CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS           BOSTON
```

But, when you `set pagesize 0` ... no heading:

```
SQL> set pagesize 0
SQL> select * From dept;
        10 ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH             DALLAS
        30 SALES                CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS           BOSTON

SQL>
```

Comment: Removing the set pagesize 0 condition adds the column headers but also adds the character _ _ _ _ _ _ _ after the column names. Can we  get rid of those.

Comment: Huh, it doesn't for me ... I'd look at it, but I can't reproduce what you are saying.

Comment: It could be related to the version of sqlplus,powershell , I am using "SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production" ,powershell PSVersion 5.1. Also I have added the excel output after removing set pagesize 0 condition.